# How to skip over a nested dictionary when iterating over it's parent dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how dictionaries work. I am trying to retrieve the name of the drink along with it's price, but I am still grabbing the ingredients as well and am unsure how to bypass them.

```
menu = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {'ingredients': {
        "water": 200,
        "milk": 150,
        "coffee": 24,
    }, 'cost': 2.5},
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

 elif selection == "menu":
            print("Please choose your drink:\n")
            for drink in menu:
                for cost in menu[drink].values():
                    print(f"{drink.capitalize()}: ${cost}0")
```

This has given me the result:

```
Espresso: ${'water': 50, 'coffee': 18}0
Espresso: $1.50
Latte: ${'water': 200, 'milk': 150, 'coffee': 24}0
Latte: $2.50
Cappuccino: ${'water': 250, 'milk': 100, 'coffee': 24}0
Cappuccino: $3.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.values()` which selects every value you just want to get costs.

So you can just use

```
menu[drink]["cost"]
```

You also dont need the second loop.
Try this:

```
for drink in menu:
    print(f"{drink.capitalize()}: ${menu[drink]['cost']}0")

Espresso: $1.50
Latte: $2.50
Cappuccino: $3.00
```